# How to see Query Execution Time in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am not able to see any query execution time option ORACLE DB's PL/SQL in JetBrain's DataGrip. There are no any help about this in JetBrain's help pages.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DataGrip version used? Should work in upcoming 2017.1 -- see original ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3063

Comment: I believe my problem is the version then. I am using one of older one. Thanks for the headsup @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is going to be solved with the 2017.1 version of DataGrip.
For Details : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3063

Comment: *"is going to be solved"* Do not theorize -- try it -- [2017.1 final was released yesterday](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/03/22/datagrip-2017-1-released/) :)