# Why does DataGrip only show query execution time sometimes?

Tags: datagrip

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945749/how-to-see-query-execution-time-in-datagrip) (and the link posted in the comments, DataGrip should show query execution time in the status bar as of version 2017.1. However, this only works for me with some queries.

E.g., on a short query, I see the following, as expected

[image]

But on some other queries, I see something like this instead

[image]

I can't really figure out when the second one happens and when it doesn't. The best guess I have is that it's only for long-running queries. But this is exactly when I would *want* it to show the execution time, so that would be very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries took longer than 20 secs give more information in output and status bar gives only the last row of it.

Anyway, looks bad, so there's a ticket:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7164